# webdriverbackedselenium in python

Tags: python, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way of using webdriverbackedselenium in python, as in

> selenium =
>   webdriverbackedselenium(driver,"http://www.google.com")

Comment: *webdriverbackedselenium*, now there's a word to remember for Scrabble :-)

Comment: let me know when you'll score with it!

Comment: As a workaround, you might be able to call it via Jython or IronPython, using the Java and .NET bindings. But I haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, one could manually write wrapper class that routes Selenium RC calls to WebDriver equivalent. I did some work on that for PHP, it's not that hard, though not all functions can be ported, but a majority can. And the process is similar across languages in terms of code flow / algorithm to wrap the calls.